# How to detect user interaction with `MapControl` on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `MapControl` and want to detect if the user has panned or zoomed the map (or basically generated any pointer events).

I've tried a number of approaches but haven't been able to detect the pointer events. E.g. `MyMapControl.PointerPressed += ...`, `MyMapControl.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerPressedEvent, ..., true)`, `Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed +=`, `((Page)this).PointerPressed +=`, but they aren't called. The events for the page and the window are emitted when touching down outside the `MapControl`, but never when touching down inside the `MapControl`.

If I put something that covers the `MapControl`, e.g. a `Rectangle`, it gets the events, but it also consumes them so they don't reach the `MapControl`. I'm hoping that it's possible for the overlay to see the events but not consume them, but haven't succeeded so far.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `MapTapped` event handles tapping the map, the generic `Tapped` event doesn't work.

As for panned or zoomed, I use the `LoadingStatusChanged` event and look for `mapControl.LoadingStatus == MapLoadingStatus.Loaded` to know when the user has stopped manipulating the map.

Note that things like drawing elements on the map will also trigger `LoadingStatusChanged`.  If that is a situation you need to deal with, you can store the map's center and zoom level somewhere, and then compare these values to the current center/zoom level of the map when the even fires to know if the map was really manipulated.

If you're using Interactivity, I wrote a behavior that does all of this if you want it.

Comment: Thanks Paul!
`MapTapped` is only fired when the user taps the map, not when they pan or zoom, so it doesn't solve my problem.
`LoadingStatusChanged` is also fired when I programatically manipulate the map, e.g. calls `TrySetViewAsync()`

Comment: The `CenterChanged` and `ZoomLevelChanged` events will let you know when interaction is occurring.